# swift .の前の省略された文を教えてください　.AspectFillとか.Nearestなど

Tags: swift, xcode

プログラミング初心者です、検索しても答え見つからないので質問させてもらいます。

例えばこの記述

```
// 背景画像を読み込む
let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "background")
texture.filteringMode = .Nearest
```

の `= .Nearest`の.の前の省略？された文を教えてください
  `.Nearest`の.の前に記述があるのは勉強したことあるが忘れてしまいました。
swift補助機能がでないので省略された記述を知りたいです。

似た文で

```
scene = GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
    scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
    skView.presentScene(scene)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

こういう場合は、式の右辺だけ見ずに、左辺も注目します。

```
texture.filteringMode = .Nearest
```

プロパティ`filteringMode`の型を調べれば、右辺の値の型もわかるはずです。
Optionキーを押しながら、`filteringMode`をクリックすると、バルーンヘルプが表示されます。（下図）

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

`filteringMode`の型が`SKTextureFilteringMode`なので、`.Nearest`を省略せずに書くと、`SKTextureFilteringMode.Nearest`であるとわかります。

Answer (score 2):

それは、型が自明な変数に代入する場合、enumの型名を省略できる というSwiftの構文です。

よって、`SKTexture.filteringMode`プロパティの型を確認すると、省略されたのが`SKTextureFilteringMode`であると分かります。

"似た文で"の方も`GameScene.scaleMode`の型を調べると分かります。

Answer (score 1):

初めまして。
SKTextureFilteringMode.Nearestです。